# Raspberry PI Zero, pushbutton and pullup

Tags: raspberry-pi, wiring, pullup, button

I have a very simple schematic:

`GPIO12 -> pushbutton -> R(1.5 Kohm) -> ground`

[image]

The GPIO12 is set to `IN` mode and internal `pullup` resistor is enabled.

With [gpio](http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/) tool from wiringpi package I am trying to detect the falling edge when the button is pressed:

`gpio wfi 26 falling` ( GPIO12 is numbered as 26 in WiringPi )

For whatever reason that doesn't work.

If I change the wiring in the way:

`+5V -> pushbutton -> R(1.5Kohm) -> GPIO12`

[image]

and configure GPIO12 pin to `IN` mode and `pulldown` internal resistor is enabled - everything works as expected, I can detect raising edge just fine.

Am I missing something with my schematics for pullup? Or there's something else involved, that I don't know about?

Comment: What is the reason for 1.5kOhms? Did you check with a very low value of say 100 ohms or less? Denouncing? Can you also draw the schematic section of the buttons?

Comment: What is the reason for 1.5kOhms? Did you check with a very low value of say 100 ohms or less? Denouncing? Can you also draw the schematic section of the buttons?

Comment: Measure the voltage at the pin GPIO26 for first configuration with push button pressed and push button released with a DMM

Comment: Your diagram shows GPIO12, but you are talking about GPIO26... Which is right?

Comment: @RonBeyer that www.circuit-diagram.or seem to use BCM numbering, where GPIO12 is GPIO26 in wiring pi: https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin32_gpio12

Comment: The Pi has about 50kOhm of internal pull-ups pulldown.. so 1.5kOhm is okay. Can you measure the voltages once at the GPIO12 once?

Comment: Pullup should be connected to 3.3V right? I don't think the chip is 5V one

Comment: @User323693 I measured the voltage between GPIO12 and GND:
with button depressed it is **3.255V**, with button pressed it is **1.650V**. Do definitely there should be an edge detected. Perhaps I should try with a resistor for 500ohm, 1500 could be just too much.

Comment: @jdevelop nope. 1.65 V is neither zero nor one for the Pi. There is a problem. With internal pull-up of 50kOhms.. the Voltage at the pin has to be close to 0V. Check the resistor value again with DMM